How to auto-adjust rows in desktop vs mobile view(responsive) in bootstrap
enter image description here
this is the white space im referring to
this is my HTML code for ref where im using the row class

        <middle>
            <div class="row custom-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div id=MyCarousel class="carousel slide" data-ride=carousel>
                        <!--global parent div-->
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#MyCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
                            </li>
                            <li data-target="#MyCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
                                <!--please refer note on div-->
                            </li>

and below is an example of my CSS
.custom-row {
    height: 300px; /* Default height */
}

/* Media query for iPhone 14 Pro Max */
@media (max-width: 430px) and (max-height: 932px) {
    .custom-row {
        height: 200px; /* Adjusted height for iPhone 14 Pro Max */
    }
}

/* Media query for iPad Mini */
@media (max-width: 768px) and (max-height: 1024px) {
    .custom-row {
        height: 250px; /* Adjusted height for iPad Mini */
    }
}


